# Use enum from dll

Tags: c++, c++11, dll, enums

I'm exporting some functions from a dll, and in some functions as a parameter I'm using enum, declaring in the dll project. What is a proper for the projects that will use this dll to find out about this enum, if they will use dll via explicit linking with LoadLibarary/GetProcAddress functions?

In implicit linking it seems easy, I just include this enum when including dll's headers.

Is in case of explicit  linking I still need to include my dll's header with enum to the project that will use the dll?

Comment: @bolov I've never used variables from a dll, searching now about info about that. If you have some good articles in mind would really appreciate the link

Comment: @bolov variables have an address, so we can access them via GetProcAddress as well, but I need enum to pass it as a parameter to exported function, not getting some variable of type enum from the dll

Comment: @Bruice Any program that wants to call your DLL function via `GetProcAddress()` will need the enum declaration beforehand, whether that comes from a header file, or is otherwise declared manually in the program's own code. Because of this, enums aren't portable to all compilers/languages, so you might consider using a plain integer parameter instead of an enum parameter.  You can use enums inside your DLL code all you want.